# phpmyadmin cron upgrade issue on NGINX with PHP7.0

Tags: git, shell, cron

I followed this [tutorial on installing phpmyadmin](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpmyadmin-with-php7/replies/124796) on NGINX with PHP7.0 and the issue I have is that my Cron job does not seem to work.

When I login to phpmyadmin I can see that it hasn't been upgraded to the latest version.

I followed the tutorial exactly like it is written except I changed the script to:

```
cd /etc/phpmyadmin/ git pull -q origin STABLE
```

My phpmaydmin is located at /etc/phpmyadmin/.

Is there anything I have missed?

Best regards.

Comment: Is that really how your script appears or did a linebreak not appear properly in the rendered output? As it currently appears, you're passing six arguments to 'cd' and not doing any work with 'git'.

Comment: Hi, I have modified it now to be -->  
`cd /etc/phpmyadmin/` one 1 line and `git pull -q origin STABLE`on the other line.

Comment: What happens when you run your script manually?

Comment: I tried to run `sh /usr/share/phpmyadmin/pma_update.sh` but it did not work either. This is my crontab [link](http://imgur.com/R4IsPLP) and this my pma_update.sh [link](http://imgur.com/he3RwsE).

Comment: Please post the full error message you get when you try to run your script.

Comment: Is `/etc/phpmyadmin` really where you checked out the git repository? While you're welcome to do whatever you want on your file system, `/etc/` is usually expected to be used for configuration files, so most people would put the git repository in another location such as `/usr/local/src/` or `/var/www/`. What user are you running the script as? Which user owns `/etc/phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Yes `/etc/phpmyadmin` is where I checked it out. I did not know that regarding the `/etc/` directory. :) The owner is `root`. Where do I find the `error log` for this?

Comment: I have solved it! All files needed to be owned by `root` in order for it to work! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which operating system are you using?

Are you sure phpmyadmin has been updated in the STABLE repositories?

Redirect your cron job to a log file:

`0 5 * * * /home/user/scripts/pma_update.sh >> /home/user/scripts/update.log`

It might be permissions or environment variables not available on cron.

Comment: It did not write to the update.log. Strange? Could it be wrong with pma_update.sh file?

Comment: What's on `/home/user/scripts/pma_update.sh` ? Did you set the proper permissions on that file? Is there any output when you run the script directly as root?

Comment: The permissions are set to `root` on that file. It contains `#!/bin/bash` and `cd /etc/phpmyadmin/` and `git pull -q origin STABLE`

Comment: I solved it all files needed to be owned by `root`! :)